# What is the unit of Canvas's size when I use Compose?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

In Code A, I get `val width = this.size.width` when I use `Canvas` of Compose.

Could you tell me what the unit of the `width`?  is it `px`? or is it `dp`?

**Code A**

```
  Box(
        modifier=Modifier.matchParentSize()
    ){           
        Canvas(
            modifier = Modifier                   
        ) {
            
            val width = this.size.width 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Canvas size comes from DrawScope interface which is `Size` that contains `Float` properties `width` and `height` which is in `px`.

[image]

```
interface DrawScope : Density {

    /**
     * The current [DrawContext] that contains the dependencies
     * needed to create the drawing environment
     */
    val drawContext: DrawContext

    /**
     * Center of the current bounds of the drawing environment
     */
    val center: Offset
        get() = drawContext.size.center

    /**
     * Provides the dimensions of the current drawing environment
     */
    val size: Size
        get() = drawContext.size

    /**
     * The layout direction of the layout being drawn in.
     */
    val layoutDirection: LayoutDirection

  // draw functions
}
```

And `Canvas` is a `Spacer` with `Modifier.drawBehind`

```
@Composable
fun Canvas(modifier: Modifier, onDraw: DrawScope.() -> Unit) =
    Spacer(modifier.drawBehind(onDraw))
```

because `onDraw` being a lambda with `DrawScope` receiver we access `DrawScope` properties.

Comment: Thanks! What's default unit ?

Comment: And, how can I get the unit?

Comment: It's `Float` for width and height which can be said px. You can easily confirm this with Modifier.fillMaxSize() which will give your screen dimensions minus status bar for height in px. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22943393/why-pixels-is-float